# Python 3.6 - установка MySQL (Windows)

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, python-3.6, mysqlconnector

Здравствуйте!

Вот уже несколько часов установить MySQL под Python 3.6, но столкнулся с рядом проблем. Перепробовал все предложенные решения на стаке, гитхабе и т.д., но всё равно не получается!

Пробовал:

- устанавливать **MySQL** с https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient - не найден модуль __main__
- устанавливать **MySQLdb** - *fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: config-win.h: No such file or directory* + *command 'D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2*
- **easy_install MySQL-python** - ошибка аналогична предыдущей
- устанавливать **TAlib**
- и т.д.

Поможете?

Comment: PyMySQL можете скачать https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL `pip install PyMySQL`

Comment: Смысле что дальше. У вас проблема с установкой или с чем

Comment: задал глупый вопрос, спасибо

Comment: а.. даже после установки - модуля pymysql всё равно не существует

Comment: что значит не существует, где это написано ? `import pymysql` или на что у вас ошибк

Comment: при компиляции ошибка "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'"

Comment: Или я как-то неправильно его подключил?

Comment: А какие действия вы вообще выполняете?

Comment: pip install pymysql [успешно]
import pymysql [не найден]

Comment: попробуйте через консоль. Если в консоли все нормально то проблема в  вашем интерпритаторе

Comment: Если вы про установку через консоль - то я так и делаю

Comment: нет, я через вызов `import pymysql`

Comment: видимо, таки, да. Через консоль всё работает

Comment: В таком случае, не подскажете, что мне делать?

Comment: переустановил pymysql через pycharm и заработало, спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется модули не в тот питон встали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы добавить библиотеку в `PyCharm` вам нужно в этом интерпретаторе зайти `Settings` -> ваш проект у меня это `Project: try` -> `Project Interpeter` или можно просто ввести в поиске `Settings` `Project Interpeter` там нажимаете `+`  и добавляете библиотеку которая вам нужна 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, разобрался уже :)